# jQuery fadeOut delay not working first time after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, delay, fadeout

I have implemented the following code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: "id="+id,
        url: 'xyz.php',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){                
            $('#message_'+id).html('Estás de acuerdo<span class="msg_order_close"></span>').show().fadeOut('slow').delay('5000');

        }
});
```

Here I have used `fadeOut('slow').delay('5000');` to hide content after 5 seconds. But it doesn't work 1st time after page has stopped loading on 1st ajax request. And it works very well after 1st request. The content will be hide after 5 seconds. On the 1st time new appended content will be hide immediately.

Suggestions will be accepted.

Comment: Don't you want the delay to come before the fadeOut like this: `.show().delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're waiting **after** hidding your content. Put the `.delay()` part **before** de fadeOut() function.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: "id="+id,
        url: 'xyz.php',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){                
            $('#message_'+id).html('Estás de acuerdo<span class="msg_order_close"></span>').show().delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');

        }
});
```

Also, 5000 is not a string, so you should remove the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delay before fading out, you will need to switch the order:

```
.delay(5000).fadeOut('slow')
```

(Credit to @tabz100 for seeing that first)

Now if you want to fade out for a length of 5 seconds, then use

```
.fadeOut(5000, 'slow')
```